# boost::recursive_wrapper and std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, smart-pointers, boost-variant

Currently (since *C++11*) it is simple to design [`boost::recursive_wrapper`](https://github.com/boostorg/variant/blob/develop/include/boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp) using `std::unique_ptr`:

```
template< typename T >
class recursive_wrapper
{

    std::unique_ptr< T > storage;

public :

    template< typename ...Args >
    recursive_wrapper(Args &&... args)
        : storage(std::make_unique< T >(std::forward< Args >(args)...))
    { ; }

    template< typename R >
    operator R & () noexcept
    {
        return static_cast< R & >(*storage);
    }

    template< typename R >
    operator R const & () const noexcept
    {
        return static_cast< R const & >(*storage);
    }

    void
    swap(recursive_wrapper & other) noexcept
    {
        storage.swap(other.storage);
    }

};
```

But currently it designed via operator `::new` and `boost::checked_delete`. It is considered a bad practice to use raw `new` and `delete` operators in modern C++.

If target is only *C++11* and newer, are there any downsides to implement `recursive_wrapper` using `std::unique_ptr` as it is above (I mean both compile-time performance and run-time performance degradation for example or maybe something else)? What if backward compatibility as a requirement ceased to exist?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find that the reason not to do this has nothing to do with performance.

`boost::recursive_wrapper` was specifically designed to allow `boost::variant`s to contain themselves. I'm pretty sure that if you check the implementation of `boost::variant` you'll find that template expansion of  a recursive template relies on specialisations that look something like this:

```
template<class...T> 
struct SomeClass<boost::recursive_wrapper<boost::variant<T...>>> 
{
    ....
```

Which, unless you are planning to re-implement `boost::variant` to use a different wrapper class, would make them incompatible.

Comment: I am not planning to use custom implementation of `recursive_wrapper` for namely `boost::variant`, but for [another implementation of variant](https://github.com/mapbox/variant). There no such an issue for that implementation. Are there any other downsides imaginable?

Comment: @Orient no, I don't think so. You'll have to remember to custom-code the copy constructor and copy operator *if* T supports those operations.

Comment: `T` is incomplete if I use it to define recursive structures, so type traits are not well-formed for `recursive_wrapper< T >` at point of its instantiation. [There is workaround](https://github.com/tomilov/variant/blob/master/include/versatile/recursive_wrapper.hpp#L31), I know it and I use it.